# Remove block after last dash in url using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, sed, preg-replace

Old web has url in this form:

```
www.oldwebsite.com/something-d801.htm 
or www.oldwebsite.com/something-something-806.htm
```

I want to remove part after last dash because without last part I have same exact url as new website (`www.newwebsite.com/something`). I would much rather do it in php router, but I think htaccess version is much more appropriate overall.

I guess there should be something similar to regexp, but only thing I found is line to strip everything after last slash :

> You can use `sed -e 's/\(.*\)\/[^\/]*/\1/g'`

But since I dont know much about htaccess I dont know which slash I should replce by dash in this line.

Also, here's my current htaccess:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R]

RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ public/$1 [L,QSA]

# EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 7 days"
</IfModule>
FileETag MTime Size
# EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be fairly simple, add this above the first  `# EXPIRES CACHING ##`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} html?$
RewriteRule ^(.+)-([^-]+)$ $1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Placed it above Caching part but unfortunately it doesnt work and I see 404 instead (because -806.htm page does not exist on new version)

Comment: can you (just for test) use `[R,L,QSA]` instead of `[L,QSA]`, just so you can check in browser address bar if any rewrite is happening at all?

Comment: Havent noticed any difference... I tried all RL L R LR combinations (because I dont know what either of these letters mean) and they has zero impact on url. Although if I remove www from url it automatically adds it back so `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R]` lines definitely work. I also see that you have html?$ in your lines, all old site urls have htM only, is it important or no?

Comment: The question mark will allow for `l` to be optional. What is **exact** url that you use for testing?

Comment: http://www.spiral.samuel.e-solutions.cz/tricko-spiral-direct-super-bad-ds131622-doprodej should be displayed (or redirected to be percise) from https://www.spiraldirect.cz/Tricko-Spiral-Direct-SUPER-BAD-DS131622-DOPRODEJ-d908.htm but since old isnt set up on new domain yet I'm trying it by typing -d908.htm in the end of http://www.spiral.samuel.e-solutions.cz/tricko-spiral-direct-super-bad-ds131622-doprodej. I suppose it should work as additional www even in this case, right?

Comment: Wait. Do you want to redirect from one site to another? Because this rule will not do it. Also, are you sure you are editing `.htaccess` file on `spiraldirect.cz` site?

Comment: No, spiraldirect will direct to spiral.cz via DNS and spiral.cz is production domain for spiral.samuel.e-solutions.cz (where whole site is and will be hosted). So now Im editing htaccess on spiral.samuel.e-solutions.cz but if I understand everythioing right this should affect spiral.samuel.e-solutions.cz product url.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123280/discussion-between-dusan-bajic-and-vladimir-litovkin).

Answer (score 0):

In case if your are open for awk:

```
echo $url
www.oldwebsite.com/something-something-806.htm
```

Awk solution :

```
echo $url |awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="-"}{NF--}1'
www.oldwebsite.com/something-something
```

Comment: How can I run awk? Is there way to do that with some rewrite conditions in htaccess?